# Differenze tra "interscambiabile" e "intercambiabile" e tra "intercambio" e "interscambio"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Ho trovato queste parole nel dizionario: "interscambiabile", "intercambiabile", "intercambio" e "interscambio". Non riesco a capire però quali siano le differenze di significato e di uso tra tali vocaboli. Potreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Intercambio* non è molto usato, almeno [secondo il De Mauro](http://www.internazionale.it/dizionario/lemma/58322/intercambio): io lo userei solo per definire il rapporto di cambio tra due monete. Per quanto riguarda *interscambiabile* / *intercambiabile* direi che le differenze sono proprio minime: userei il primo quando A e B si scambiano tra di loro ("i loro ruoli sono interscambiabili" significa che possiamo mettere uno nella posizione dell'altro e non cambia nulla) e il secondo quando si possono cambiare dei pezzi in un singolo oggetto ("il robot da cucina ha varie parti intercambiabili": resta sempre lo stesso robot, solo con il macinacarne o la frusta).